# Cartoon in which Batman shot Zoom in the head

Tags: story-identification, dc, cartoon

Zoom was weak. Upon being asked, he removed his yellow mask to reveal a big hole on his forehead.

He further explained that he had almost destroyed Earth in an alternate reality. Even Flash was unable to stop him. But, he didn't see it coming. Batman shot him right at his head. At that very moment, he vibrated and rearranged his brain to protect it and mustered all of his speed force to extend his life for few weeks.

Can you please identify this cartoon and the episode? Also, I want to know the exact episode in which Batman shot Zoom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found YouTube clips. Both are from movies, not episodes. The one where Zoom reveals he was shot seems to be *Suicide Squad: Hell to Pay*:

And the one where he gets shot is apparently *Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox*: